# OpenCV - Image Processing Technique for better reading of embossed characters (e.g in credit cards,plate number)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, ocr

So, I've already searched a lot of articles about image processing of plate numbers since it is basically just the same as reading embossed characters. But my problem is if the embossed characters color is the same as the color of the card it will be hard to recognize if I use Adaptive Threshold. Do you guys have any idea on how I will achieve my goal of reading embossed characters? Or if there's any article about it, it would be nice. Here's my sample image

I've read this [article](https://www.azoft.com/blog/ocr-embossed-text/) but don't really know how to translate it into actual code.

Here's my sample image
[image]

Comment: Hey, I read the article, and it sounds pretty clear. But I didn't try to implement it, and maybe that's more difficult than it appears :) What's wrong with it?

Comment: Im new to developing this kind of application, maybe that's why :) I actually found the whole sample code for C, unfortunately Im using Java and honestly I have no idea on how to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/) code. It's in python but all the opencv methods are, from my personal experience, quite the same as Java.

EDIT:
In your case, you can skip all the OCR enhancement methods used here. Let me describe the process you can use:

**In python using the link above:**

First, apply a color conversion to grayscale:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Then:
apply a tophat (whitehat) morphological operator to find light
regions against a dark background.

```
rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 3))
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, rectKernel)
```

You may need to use a threshold before doing this because your image has not many contrast.

```
gradX = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gradX, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Apply a second closing operation to the binary image to make regions appear and  close gaps between credit card number regions

```
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))    
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)
```

Then find contours of your card numbers regions

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
locs = []
```

You will get an array of regions you will be able to extract using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853838/extract-area-detected-by-color-using-opencv-in-android)

**In Java:**

I previously wrote something similar in java, you should have something similar to this (ImgTransformation is one of my class that simplifies some opencv parameters, it basically does the same as Imgproc, go check the doc [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/imgproc.html)):

Image transformation:

```
ImgTransformation.adjustConvertColor(tempMat,tempMat,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(tempMat,tempMat,255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,31,40);

ImgTransformation.gaussianBlur(tempMat,tempMat,5,5,2);
Mat element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*1 + 1, 2*1+1));
Imgproc.dilate(tempMat,tempMat,element);
Imgproc.erode(tempMat,tempMat,element);
ImgTransformation.adjustBinary(tempMat,tempMat,205,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

Segmentation:

```
Mat structuringElements = ImgSegmentation.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(5, 3));
Imgproc.dilate(tempMat,tempMat,structuringElements,new Point(-1,-1),16);
```

Then extract regions:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = ImgSegmentation.findContours(tempMat, tempMat);
```

You just have then to extract using `submat()` and you're good !
Play with some numeric parameters to tune the result in your own case as my project is more about scanned documents than credit card numbers.

Good luck !